# Dependency("lodash") not found error running mocha test in browser

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js, lodash

I have following AMD exported module to be tested

```
define(['lodash', 'log', './xxx'], function(_, log, XXX) {
 ......
});
```

I'm using the following [mocha](/questions/tagged/mocha) test script (*myTest.js*), which used above script as a dependency:

```
define(["../../../yyy"], function(YYY) {
    describe("Sample Module", function() {

        it('should have a name', function() {
            expect(YYY.name).to.be.a("string");

        });

    });

    return {
        name: "modulespec"
    }
});
```

And using following test runner to run it on browser:

```
<div id="mocha"></div>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config(
        {
            baseUrl:'js/',
            paths:{
                'jquery':'lib/jquery'
            }
        }
    );

    require(['require', 'lib/chai', 'lib/mocha'], function(require){
        mocha.setup('bdd');
        require(['spec/myTest'], function(module){
            console.log("module: ", module);
            mocha.run();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting following error while running the test on the browser:

> require.js:1677 GET file:///home/malintha/projects/.../mocha/js/lodash.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

How can I include "lodash" dependency to solve this issue?

My folder structure is:

```
.
├── js
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── chai.js
│   │   ├── mocha.js
│   │   ├── module-b.js
│   │   ├── require.js
│   │   └── should.js
│   ├── SampleModule.js
│   └── spec
│       |
│       └── myTest.js
├── mocha.css
└── runner.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Lodash does not seem to be installed. RequireJS has no functionality to find and install libraries automatically for you.

You need to install it first. You could do `npm install lodash-amd` to get a copy in a `node_modules` subdirectory. You can use whatever method you want provided that you install a build of Lodash as an AMD module (or a collection of AMD modules). The NPM package `lodash-amd` is the "official" AMD build. The thing is that RequireJS only understands modules in the AMD format. It has facilities to simplify somewhat using CommonJS modules but ultimately they need to be wrapped in `define(...)` which makes them AMD modules.

Then you need to add it to your `paths`. For instance, if you've copied it to `lib`:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl:'js/',
  paths:{
    jquery:'lib/jquery',
    lodash: 'lib/lodash',
  }
});
```